# Netbeans cargar datos en un jtable

Tags: java, java-8, jframe

Quiero hacer un programa en el cual se pueda ingresar una compra, es decir, buscar diferentes productos por su `id`, cargar uno por uno en un `JTable` como si fuera un super e ir pasando los productos.

dejo mi codigo: 
Por el momento, lo único que logré hacer es mostrar lo que necesito, pero al pasar el próximo producto, me borra en el `JTable` el que ya había anteriormente y queda ingresado solamente el nuevo, es decir, en vez de añadir, pisa el contenido.

Éste es mi código:
 DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

```
public void MostrarDatosTabla(String d, DefaultTableModel modelo) {
    Connection cnn;

    try {
        cnn = Conexion.getConexion();
        Statement smt = cnn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery("select * from productos WHERE codigoProducto  LIKE '%" + d + "%'");
        boolean ccolumnas = false;
        if (!ccolumnas) {
            ccolumnas = true;
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnas = md.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnas; i++) {
                modelo.addColumn(md.getColumnLabel(i));
            }

        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] fila = new Object[columnas];
            for (int i = 0; i < columnas; i++) {
                fila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            modelo.addRow(fila);
            //   fila=null;
        }}
        tablaa.setModel(modelo);
        cnn.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        setTitle("Problema CargarDatos" + sqlex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, que paso que eliminaste esta publicacion: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/507913/c-recorrer-datagridview-y-agregar-columna

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas crear el modelo fuera del método que muestras:

En algún lugar de tu programa creas el modelo y lo pones a la tabla:

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
tablaa.setModel(modelo);
```

El método que va a llenar la tabla le pasas el modelo para que te lo actualice:

```
public void MostrarDatosTabla(String d, DefaultTableModel modelo) { ...
```

y en ese método quitas estas líneas para que no vuelva a iniciar el modelo cada vez:

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
tablaa.setModel(modelo);
```

Ahora que cada vez que invocas el método estás agregando columnas. Para no agregar columnas cada vez, si es que no sabes con anticipación cuantas columnas vas a requerir para el modelo, puedes usar alguna variable global, por ejemplo:

```
  var columnasDefinidas = false;
```

Y en el método puedes cambiarías esa parte así:

```
if (!columnasDefinidas) {
    columnasDefinidas = true;
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnas = md.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnas; i++) {
        modelo.addColumn(md.getColumnLabel(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Me sirvio lo que me dijiste, pero al insertar una segunda fila, tambien me inserta otras 5 columnas mas, asi sucesivamente.. como hago para que no toque el tema de las columnas, es decir que queden fijas las que son

Comment: @CubaGarcia, ya edité mi respuesta para aclarar ese punto. No sé si lo entiendas ahora.

Comment: Alberto, si ya habia intentado con algo asi, pero sigue agregando columnas.

Comment: ¿puedes mostrar el código nuevo?

Comment: Listo, actualice el codigo de arriba.

Comment: @CubaGarcia "boolean ccolumnas = false;"   Esa línea necesitas sacarla del método.  Pon esa línea en un lugar donde solo se ejecute una vez y no cada vez que invoques el método.

Comment: al mover esa variable fuera del metodo, el sistema realiza una sola vez la consulta, muestra el dato y luego no muestra mas nada.

Comment: @CubaGarcia  tienes este if "if (!ccolumnas) {", necesitas cerrarlo antes del while de abajo. O sea  modelo.addColumn(md.getColumnLabel(i));             } } <<< cierra el módulo del if antes del while

Comment: Listo, estaba mal interpretado el While!! MILES DE GRACIAS ALBERTO

Comment: de nada, si quieres saber cuantas columnas puedes preguntarlo al modelo: int columnas = modelo.getColumnCount();

Comment: Excelente.. otra consulta, como seria el metodo, para verificar si un producto que cargo ya esta en la lista, que a dicha columna le sume uno mas. Es decir, el producto se carga una sola vez en la tabla, lo cual una fila va a tener un valor = 1, y si luego cargo otro con el mismo codigo que a ese valor le sume x veces este repetido :)

Comment: Necesitas buscar el producto en el modelo (DefaultTableModel) requieres iterarlo para ver si tienes ese producto. Si quieres mejor respuesta necesitas publicar otra pregunta, para que te sea más clara la respuesta. Puedes también usar un HashMap para meter los productos que metas al modelo. Depende de que tantos productos tengas para ver cual sería mejor.

Comment: Listo ya subi otra pregunta.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248073/netbeans-datos-duplicado-en-jtable