# Netbeans datos duplicado en jtable

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy intentando generar un sistema de venta, en el cual se ingresa un código, busca los datos y lo carga en un `JTable`. Mi idea es que si el producto que cargo ya está ingresado, solamente le sume uno a la columna correspondiente que ya está cargada, de lo contrario cargaría la fila con los datos correspondientes.

Adjunto mi código el cual no está funcionando correctamente, sino que lo carga varias veces al mismo producto.

```
boolean ccolumnas = false;
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

public void MostrarDatosTabla(String d, DefaultTableModel modelo) {
    Connection cnn;
    try {
        cnn = Conexion.getConexion();
        Statement smt = cnn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery("select codigoProducto, descripcionProducto, precio, cantidad from productos WHERE codigoProducto  LIKE '%" + d + "%'");
        String[] registros = new String[4];
        String num = "1";
        int fila = tablaa.getSelectedRow();
        if (!ccolumnas) {
            ccolumnas = true;
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnas = md.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnas; i++) {
                modelo.addColumn(md.getColumnLabel(i));
            }
        }
        while (rs.next()) {
            String regi = rs.getString("codigoProducto");
            registros[0] = rs.getString("codigoProducto");
            registros[1] = rs.getString("descripcionProducto");
            registros[2] = rs.getString("precio");
            if (d.equals(regi)) {
                String precio = tablaa.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString();
                int numero1 = Integer.parseInt(precio);
                int numero = Integer.parseInt(num);
                int suma = numero1 + numero;
                String tot = Integer.toString(suma);
                registros[3] = tot;
            } else {
                registros[3] = num;
            }
            modelo.addRow(registros);
        }
        tablaa.setModel(modelo);
        cnn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Con este método podemos buscar el producto en el modelo.

```
private int buscaProductoEnModelo(String codigo, DefaultTableModel modelo) {
  if (codigo != null && modelo != null) {
     for (int renglon = 0; renglon <modelo.getRowCount(); renglon++) {
         String codigoEnRenglon = (String)modelo.getValueAt(renglon, 0);
         if (codigo.equals(codigoEnRenglon)) {
           return renglon;
        }
 }
 return -1;
}
```

Para luego cambiar el método donde actualizas tabla:

```
public void MostrarDatosTabla(String d, DefaultTableModel modelo) {

  //primero buscas en modelo para evitar buscar en base de datos si ya está en modelo.
 int renglon = buscaProductoEnModelo(d, modelo);
 if (renglon>=0) { //si encontró el producto ya en modelo
     int total = Integer.parseInt(modelo.getValueAt(renglon, 3); //esto esta ineficiente y peligroso, cambiar a Integer esta columna
     total == ?? //aquí no entiendo bien como actualizas el precio o el total
                 //pero creo tú lo puedes hacer y lo actualizas con siguiente línea:
     modelo.setValueAt(Integer.toString(total), renglon, 3);
     modelo.fireTableRowsUpdated(renglon, renglon); //necesitamos avisarle al modelo que ha cambiado para que se muestre el cambio en la tabla.
 }
 else {

  Connection cnn;
  try {
    cnn = Conexion.getConexion();
    Statement smt = cnn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery("select codigoProducto, descripcionProducto, precio, cantidad from productos WHERE codigoProducto  LIKE '%" + d + "%'");
    String[] registros = new String[4];
    String num = "1";
    int fila = tablaa.getSelectedRow();
    if (!ccolumnas) {
        ccolumnas = true;
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnas = md.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnas; i++) {
            modelo.addColumn(md.getColumnLabel(i));
        }
        tablaa.setModel(modelo); //aqui seteas el modelo y no cada vez!
    }
    while (rs.next()) {
        String regi = rs.getString("codigoProducto");
        registros[0] = rs.getString("codigoProducto");
        registros[1] = rs.getString("descripcionProducto");
        registros[2] = rs.getString("precio");
        if (d.equals(regi)) {
            String precio = tablaa.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString();
            int numero1 = Integer.parseInt(precio);
            int numero = Integer.parseInt(num);
            int suma = numero1 + numero;
            String tot = Integer.toString(suma);
            registros[3] = ?? //no entiendo como calculas este dato para
                              //el primer producto.
        }
        modelo.addRow(registros);
    }
  //   tablaa.setModel(modelo);
    cnn.close();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
 }
}
```

Comment: Relamente sos el genio de los genio!! MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!!

Comment: @CubaGarcia por favor, acepta la respuesta como correcta para que quede de referencia a futuras búsquedas de problemas similares.